# Keras load_model and get_default_graph.finalize()

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a trouble when I'm trying finalize loaded graph. My pipeline is next:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.models import load_model

model = load_model("model")
model.load_weights("weights")
graph = tf.get_default_graph()
graph.finalize()
```

But I have error like this:

```
RuntimeError: Graph is finalized and cannot be modified.
```

The question is why it is happened? I'm trying finalize graph AFTER loading model and weights and it should work correct, so I can't get this behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to load your model inside within multithreading you need to clear session

```
from keras import backend as K
K.clear_session()
```